# What is the workaround for the "TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError" error when transferring "spl-tokens"?

Tags: spl-token, blockhash, block, block-time

You've created a wallet feature using the Web3js SDK.

I created functions related to Solana and SPL-token retrieval and transfer and used them well. However, recently I am getting an error when transferring SPL-tokens.

I tried various methods to fix the error, but it was not possible to fix the error.

Below is the Javascript code I used before and the code I have modified now.

Do any of these codes require additional settings or other methods to fix the error?

Or is this a bug in the Solana  node network?

**old code**

```
  const myMint = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(req.query.contract);
  const myToken = new splToken.Token(
    conn,
    myMint,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromWallet
  );
  let toWallet = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(req.query.to);
  const fromTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
    fromWallet.publicKey
  );
  const toTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
    toWallet
  );
  amount = req.query.amount * Math.pow(10, 8)
  // Add token transfer instructions to transaction
  const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction()
    .add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        amount
      )
    );
  // Sign transaction, broadcast, and confirm
  const signature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    conn,
    transaction,
    [fromWallet] , 
    { commitment: 'confirmed',   skipPreflight: true}
  );
```

**change code1**

```
const modifyComputeUnits = solanaWeb3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 300_000
});

const addPriorityFee = solanaWeb3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 10
});


let latestBlockhash = await conn.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction({
  feePayer : fromWallet.publicKey , 
  blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight
})
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
  splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    fromWallet.publicKey,
    [],
    amount
  )
);

const transactionSignature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  conn,
  transaction,
  [fromWallet] , 
  { commitment: 'confirmed',   skipPreflight: true}
);
```

**change code2**

```
let latestBlockhash = await conn.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");

const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction({
  feePayer : fromWallet.publicKey , 
  blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
})
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
  splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    fromWallet.publicKey,
    [],
    amount
  )
);
const message = transaction.serializeMessage();
const signature = nacl.sign.detached(message, fromWallet.secretKey);
transaction.addSignature(fromWallet.publicKey, Buffer.from(signature));


const transactionSignature = await conn.sendRawTransaction(
  transaction.serialize(),
  { commitment: 'confirmed', skipPreflight: true , maxRetries: 150 }
);

const latestBlockHash = await conn.getLatestBlockhash();
const tx = await conn.confirmTransaction(transactionSignature, { 
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    commitment: 'confirmed', skipPreflight: true , maxRetries: 150
 });
```

Error Msg : TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 53fgvUBnx9L57Xt3GcRqwUbQXNZmbCo6Vcu53UiFzHPoQHbPpDPNvpWcSJFday2heYU2QVpDLWUekZNotajRd4Lh has expired: block height exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

Add higher priority fee, probably same of higher than avg priority fee of last block, 10micolamports too low now a days on solana due to high traffic on chain